# Github pages blog + feedburner feed doesn't work

Tags: rss, github, feed, feedburner

I forked TPW's blog from github and built my blog around it. It's a rough version which I'd like to customize. I changed the RSS feed details from his to mine but it can't get my feedburner feed to work.

Feedvalidator.org gets me this error:

"It looks like this is a web page, not a feed. I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn't find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate."

So I don't get redirected to the standard feedburner page where you could subscribe, but rather to a css-less version of my homepage.

The new version of Google feedburner gets me this error:

"Error on line 57: The entity "raquo" was referenced, but not declared."

I have no clue what this means as I don't have an entity named "raquo" anywhere on my website.

The old feedburner version gets me a similar error (redirected from the newer Google version):

"The URL you entered does not appear to be a valid feed. We encountered the following problem: Error on line 57: The entity "raquo" was referenced, but not declared."

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by deleting and re-creating the feed.